# Ada record representation

Tags: record, ada

I have a record type as follows:

```
type Rec_T is record
   a : Bit_12_T;
   b : Bit_4_T;
end record;
```

where `Bit_12_T is mod 2**12` and `Bit_4_T is mod 2**4`.

To tell the compiler the precise alignment of this record, I use the the `for use record` statement. However, I want to split the `a` field bewteen the bytes, so I try to do it as follows:

```
for Rec_T use record
   a at 0 range 0 .. 7; -- The 1st byte
   a at 1 range 0 .. 3; -- The 2nd byte
   b at 1 range 4 .. 7;
end record;
```

Clearly, this is not the way to do it as the compiler complains that "component clause is previously given at line ...".

**Question:** Is it possible to have a component split between the bytes and how to do it? If it is not possible, should I have a_high and a_low and then use some bit operations to merge them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the location as an array of bits, not as a sequence of bytes. Hence this should work:

```
for Rec_T use record
   a at 0 range 0 .. 11; -- bits 0..7 of the 1st byte and bits 0..3 of the 2nd byte
   b at 0 range 12 .. 15; -- bits 4..7 of the second byte
end record;
for Rec_T'Size use 16;
```

For more information see [documentation here](https://www2.adacore.com/gap-static/GNAT_Book/html/aarm/AA-13-5-1.html), specifically the example at then end of the page, that shows a similar situation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I already looked at this example; however, it only shows how to align various fields into bytes and not how to split a single field between bytes.

Comment: @NeoSer Read the docs again. There's no limitation regarding `first_bit` and `last_bit` belonging to the same byte. Think of the underlying storage as a long, consecutive array of bits.

Comment: Ondrej, shouldn’t that be `for Rec_T’Size use 16;`?

Comment: Yes, one can specify ``for Rec_T'Size use 16;``, but this only tells that the record should fit into 16 bits. In fact, any number of bits can be used, the ones that are not used in ``for Rec_T use record`` will be "marked" as unused.